Optimal fractional betting strategy to maximize expected wealth
Suppose I start with a bankroll $X_0 = 1$ and for $n$ rounds I wager a fraction $f$ of my wealth in a favorable game with symmetric odds. That is to say, I seek an optimal betting rule $f^*$ to maximize my expected wealth
$$f^* = \underset{0 \leq f \leq 1}{\arg \max} \; \mathbb{E}\left[ \left( 1 + f \right)^M \left( 1 - f \right)^{n - M} \right]$$
where $M \sim \text{Binomial}(n, p)$ for $\frac{1}{2} < p < 1$. I suspect $f^* = 1$ but I am having trouble arriving there. Defining
$$G(f) = \mathbb{E}\left[ \left( 1 + f \right)^M \left( 1 - f \right)^{n - M} \right]$$
we have
$$G(f) = \sum_{m=0}^M \Pr(M = m) \left( 1 + f \right)^m \left( 1 - f \right)^{n - m}$$
but I'm unable to identify stationary points from
$$G'(f) = \sum_{m=0}^M \Pr(M = m) \left[ m \left( 1 + f \right)^{m - 1} \left( 1 - f \right)^{n - m} - (n - m) \left( 1 + f \right)^m \left( 1 - f \right)^{n - m - 1} \right]$$

With $p>\frac12$, this a favourable bet.  Betting everything every time i.e. $f^=1$ gives you an expectation of $(2p)^n$ though a probability of losing all your wealth of $(1-p)^n$.  Showing $f^=1$ is optimal for $n=1$ gets you most of the way.

Yes, I'm aware of that result. My question is about proving that $f = 1$ is indeed optimal among all fixed fractional betting strategies.

The point is that $f=1$ is optimal for $n=1$, e.g. for the final bet, and this is easy to show even though the derivative is not zero (instead you are restricted by $0\le f\le 1$). Allowing different bets at different stages, you can then show $f=1$ is also optimal for the penultimate bet, and so on back to the first bet, i.e. $f^*=1$  for all bets.

Ok, thanks. I went through that exercise earlier today, but I am still curious if there is a way to analytically solve the optimization problem as I've formulated it (without backwards induction). At first glance it seemed simple enough...

Your $G(f)$ is similar to the probability generating function for a binomial distribution and you have $$G(f)=\big((1-p)(1-f)+p(1+f)\big)^n.$$ You can expand it to check this matches your expressions.
Its derivative with respect to $f$ is $$G'(f)= n(2p-1)\big((1-p)(1-f)+p(1+f)\big)^{n-1}$$ which is positive when $\frac12 \lt p \le 1$ and $0\le f\le 1$, so $G(f)$ is maximised when $f=1$.
